# Signal Quality/ Strength from modem Unavailable from ModemManager 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, modem-manager

I am using a MC7403 modem in 16.04 LTS.
The signal quality returned from the modem manager "mmcli -m 0" returns 0, so does the network manger, how can I get signal strength to update correctly?

After initial connection it is correct but after 30 seconds it returns 0.  The connection to the ISP and Internet still works but I can no longer monitor signal strength.
It appears modemmanger start looking at /dev/ttyUSB0 instead of /dev/ttyUSB2
At 30 seconds there is also this error in the Network manager log

IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Request

The log shows this error.

```
    Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377885.290585] [mm-iface-modem.c:1165] update_signal_quality(): Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (0)
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.290986] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1991] modem_load_signal_quality(): loading signal quality...
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.291145] [mm-iface-modem.c:934] access_technologies_check_ready(): Couldn't refresh access technologies: 'No AT port available to run command'
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.291233] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 4
```

I turned on debug and created logs. This is truncated, I could paste the whole log if helpful

```
    Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7183] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[13: 32.97.0.0/32 700]: success
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7189] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): set IP4Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/10)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7190] default-route: entry[0/dev:0x1c96c10:ttyUSB2:1:+sync]: record:add    0.0.0.0/0 via 32.97.0.0 dev 13 metric 700 mss 0 src user (700)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7190] default-route: entry[0/dev:0x1c96c10:ttyUSB2:1:+sync]: sync:add    0.0.0.0/0 via 32.97.0.0 dev 13 metric 700 mss 0 src user (700)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7190] platform: route: adding or updating IPv4 route: 0.0.0.0/0 via 32.97.0.0 dev 13 metric 700 mss 0 src user
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7201] platform: signal: route   4   added: 0.0.0.0/0 via 32.97.0.0 dev 13 metric 700 mss 0 src user scope global
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7202] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[13: 0.0.0.0/0 700]: success
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7203] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7203] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7203] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7204] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage5_ip4_config_commit,2 (id 302)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7209] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage5_ip4_config_commit,2 (id 302)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7211] platform: address: adding or updating IPv4 address: 10.92.16.64/32 lft forever pref forever lifetime 3-0[4294967295,4294967295] ptp 32.97.0.0 dev 13 src unknown
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7215] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-address[13: 10.92.16.64/32,32.97.0.0]: success
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7215] route-mgr4:  13: sync 1 IPv4 routes
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7216] platform: route: adding or updating IPv4 route: 32.97.0.0/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev 13 metric 700 mss 0 src kernel pref-src 10.92.16.64
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7217] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[13: 32.97.0.0/32 700]: success
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7218] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): remove_pending_action (1): 'dhcp4' not pending (expected)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7218] device (ttyUSB2): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7221] firewall: [0x7ff4ec00fa10,change*:"ppp0"]: firewall zone change ppp0:default (not running, simulate success)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7226] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): activation-stage: complete activate_stage5_ip4_config_commit,2 (id 302)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7243] default-route: entry[0/dev:0x1c96c10:ttyUSB2:1:-sync]: record:update 0.0.0.0/0 via 32.97.0.0 dev 13 metric 700 mss 0 src user scope global (700)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7245] firewall: [0x7ff4ec00fa10,change*:"ppp0"]: complete: fake success
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7246] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): add_pending_action (2): 'queued state change to secondaries'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7249] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): queued state change to secondaries due to none (id 307)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7250] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): running queued state change to secondaries (id 307)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7250] device (ttyUSB2): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7252] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): add_pending_action (3): 'queued state change to activated'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7253] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): queued state change to activated due to none (id 310)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7253] manager: ActivatingConnection now (none)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7254] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): device entered SECONDARIES state
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7254] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): remove_pending_action (2): 'queued state change to secondaries'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7258] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): running queued state change to activated (id 310)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7259] device (ttyUSB2): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7261] active-connection[0x1bc3130]: set state activated (was activating)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7267] connectivity: set online
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7267] connectivity: state changed from NONE to FULL
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7267] manager: connectivity checking indicates FULL
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7271] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7274] active-connection[0x1bc3130]: check-master-ready: not signalling (state activated, no master)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7339] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): remove_pending_action (1): 'activation::0x1bc3130'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7346] dns-mgr: (device_state_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7347] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): queueing DNS updates (2)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7348] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7352] policy: set 'Telstra Telstra (Next G) 1' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7352] manager: PrimaryConnection now Telstra Telstra (Next G) 1
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7354] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): DNS configuration changed
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7354] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): no DNS changes to commit (1)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7355] dns-mgr: (device_state_changed): DNS configuration changed
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7355] dns-mgr: (device_state_changed): committing DNS changes (0)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7355] dns-mgr: update-dns: updating resolv.conf
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7356] dns-mgr: update-dns: updating plugin dnsmasq
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7360] kill process 'dnsmasq' (2432): waiting up to 1000 milliseconds for process to disappear after sending SIGKILL (9)...
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7527] kill process 'dnsmasq' (2432): process is gone after sending signal SIGKILL (9) (16766 usec elapsed)
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7528] dns-plugin[0x1bbcf40]: starting dnsmasq...
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7529] dns-plugin[0x1bbcf40]: command line: /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7543] dns-plugin[0x1bbcf40]: dnsmasq started with pid 16306
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7557] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: adding nameserver '10.5.133.45'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7559] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: adding nameserver '10.5.136.242'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7560] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: dnsmasq not found on the bus. The nameserver update will be sent when dnsmasq appears
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7560] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: started, version 2.75 cache disabled
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: warning: no upstream servers configured
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7689] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7690] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): set metered value 3
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7691] manager: new metered value: 3
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7692] device[0x1c96c10] (ttyUSB2): remove_pending_action (0): 'queued state change to activated'
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7692] manager: check_if_startup_complete returns FALSE because of enp1s0
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7750] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: dnsmasq proxy creation successful
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377855.7872] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.156
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7873] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: trying to update dnsmasq nameservers
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc whoopsie[892]: [13:37:35] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: using nameserver 10.5.133.45#53
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc dnsmasq[16306]: using nameserver 10.5.136.242#53
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377855.7894] dnsmasq[0x1bbcf40]: dnsmasq update successful
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc whoopsie[892]: [13:37:35] Network connection may be a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
Dec 22 13:37:35 roamescar-pc pppd[16275]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 16286), status = 0x0
Dec 22 13:37:36 roamescar-pc gnome-session[1543]: (deja-dup-monitor:3722): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 229 was not found when attempting to remove it
Dec 22 13:37:38 roamescar-pc pppd[16275]: sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::b44b:b091:d684:2148>]
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2669] device[0x1c1e890] (enp1s0): remove_pending_action (0): 'carrier wait'
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2671] manager: check_if_startup_complete returns FALSE because of enp4s0
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2672] device[0x1c41100] (enp4s0): remove_pending_action (0): 'carrier wait'
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2672] manager: check_if_startup_complete returns FALSE because of enp3s0
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2673] device[0x1c54cb0] (enp3s0): remove_pending_action (0): 'carrier wait'
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2674] manager: check_if_startup_complete returns FALSE because of enp2s0
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <debug> [1482377859.2674] device[0x1c62060] (enp2s0): remove_pending_action (0): 'carrier wait'
Dec 22 13:37:39 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377859.2675] manager: startup complete
Dec 22 13:37:41 roamescar-pc pppd[16275]: sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::b44b:b091:d684:2148>]
Dec 22 13:37:43 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377863.2652] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Dec 22 13:37:43 roamescar-pc NetworkManager[16259]: <info>  [1482377863.2654] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Dec 22 13:37:44 roamescar-pc pppd[16275]: sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::b44b:b091:d684:2148>]
Dec 22 13:38:02 roamescar-pc pppd[16275]: message repeated 6 times: [ sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::b44b:b091:d684:2148>]]
Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc pppd[16275]: IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377885.286966] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1991] modem_load_signal_quality(): loading signal quality...
Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377885.287108] [mm-iface-modem.c:934] access_technologies_check_ready(): Couldn't refresh access technologies: 'No AT port available to run command'
Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377885.287186] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 40 7c b2 7e
Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377885.290141] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7d 5e d7 7e
Dec 22 13:38:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377885.290585] [mm-iface-modem.c:1165] update_signal_quality(): Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (0)
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.290986] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1991] modem_load_signal_quality(): loading signal quality...
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.291145] [mm-iface-modem.c:934] access_technologies_check_ready(): Couldn't refresh access technologies: 'No AT port available to run command'
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.291233] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 40 7c b2 7e
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.292423] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7d 5e d7 7e
Dec 22 13:38:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377915.292730] [mm-iface-modem.c:1165] update_signal_quality(): Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (0)
Dec 22 13:39:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377945.266642] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1991] modem_load_signal_quality(): loading signal quality...
Dec 22 13:39:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377945.266742] [mm-iface-modem.c:934] access_technologies_check_ready(): Couldn't refresh access technologies: 'No AT port available to run command'
Dec 22 13:39:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377945.266774] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 40 7c b2 7e
Dec 22 13:39:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377945.269222] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7d 5e d7 7e
Dec 22 13:39:05 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377945.269486] [mm-iface-modem.c:1165] update_signal_quality(): Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (0)
Dec 22 13:39:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377975.268692] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1991] modem_load_signal_quality(): loading signal quality...
Dec 22 13:39:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377975.268952] [mm-iface-modem.c:934] access_technologies_check_ready(): Couldn't refresh access technologies: 'No AT port available to run command'
Dec 22 13:39:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377975.269132] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 40 7c b2 7e
Dec 22 13:39:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377975.272297] [mm-port-serial-qcdm.c:201] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7d 5e d7 7e
Dec 22 13:39:35 roamescar-pc ModemManager[16197]: <debug> [1482377975.272660] [mm-iface-modem.c:1165] update_signal_quality(): Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (0)
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Instead, when you can, mark your answer as accepted using the grey checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 16.04.1 LTS kernel 4.4.* is not new enough and does not support the qmi interfaces correctly. You need to upgrade kernel or use Ubuntu 16.10 or newer.  Also the modemmanger likely needs to be upgraded.  I used PPAs provided by Aleksander to get it working in 16.04 LTS short term.

Long Answer
I was able to collect the logs above using this method [Debuging](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/Debugging/).

I collected new logs at the request of one of the libmbim developers.  From that he could see as can be seen above that it using AT+PPP.
Aleksander suggested I need a new kernel and modemmanager trying this worked.

Some notes on the modem. 
Using AT!USBCOMP? I was able to see that these modems where not configured for mbim only qmi.
I did try mbim in 16.04 LTS but it still didn't work and required an newer kernel and modem manager.

Reporting signal strength may not worry you but not using the correct interfaces also will limit your speed at least in my case.

When running with AT+PPP I was getting 35Mbps down and 18 Mbps up. Using the LTE interfaces I am getting 35-45 Mps Down and 23-29 Mbps Up